# Integration test with IOptions and KeyVault

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit

I'm trying to write an integration test for an AD Service I have in my codebase, however the service I'm testing requires IOptions to be passed in to the constructor. To make matters worse we are using azure key vault for our config.

Here is my test so far:

```
[Fact]
public void Test_GetAccessToken_GetsAccessToken()
{

    //Arrange
    var azureAdOptions = Options.Create(new AzureAd());
    
    var aadService = new MyPortal.Services.Implementations.AadService(azureAdOptions);

    //Act
    var accessToken = aadService.GetAccessToken();

    //Assert
    Assert.NotEmpty(accessToken);
}
```

This currently fails as the AzureAd object's properties are null.

> ***my question is**, how do I populate that object from Key Vault, given I'm in a test and all that stuff happens in the Startup.cs &
> Program.cs files**

This is my Program.cs file, where KeyVault is configured.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context,config) =>
        {
            var settings = config.Build();
#if (!DEBUG)
            var keyVaultName = settings["KeyVaultName"];
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(keyVaultName))
            {
                config.AddAzureKeyVault(keyVaultName);
            }
#endif
        })
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        });
}
```

Comment: I would consider mocking those values. Your program and startup classes aren't called in a unit test (unless you're using a WebApplicationFactory) so just switch out where you're calling the aad. Bear in mind, this is a unit test so shouldn't actually be making a request to your AAD

Comment: This is an integration test not a unit test, so i am interested in making sure i actually receive a token back not a fake string

Comment: In that case I'd consider looking into the WebApplicationFactory in Mvc.Testing nuget package. That will load up your program and startup file

Comment: Can you write this up as an answer so i can mark it as accepted if i get any joy with the approach please?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use a Web Application Factory if you're doing this as an integration test.

```
    var factory = new WebApplicationFactory<Program>();
    var client = factory.CreateClient();
    var response = await client.SendAsync(SomeHttpRequestMessage);
```

This should load up your entire program including startup using the actual dependencies.

This nuget package is called mvc.testing and you can find some more information on it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Comment: Having the same pb here. Integration tests should run in isolation. kv should not be part of it.